# Class E Power amplifier

Tags: power-amplifier

[image: Class E PA]

I am designing a Class E power amplifier for 450MHz frequency. But how to fix the Q factor for the series LC in the output stage of the Power amplifier?

Comment: Do you know how to read my impedance nomographs in other answers? or know how to conjugate match in Smith Charts?

Comment: I know conjugate matching using Smith charts

Comment: What Q do you want? also double tuned Q for wider BW?  Always start with design specs , not schematic.

Comment: In fact that is what I am having doubts on how much Q I must consider. The specs are RF input of 450 MHz, Vdd = 1.8V, output power of 1mW

Comment: no BW spectrum? or 3OI or IP3 values or antenna Z?

Comment: BW is from 350MHz to 500MHz. Antenna impedance is 50 ohm

Comment: This PA is connected to the VCO of a PLL. So the input power I have to consider is the power of VCO, is it??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58532/discussion-between-swap-and-tony-stewart-ee-since-75).

Comment: How much suppression of harmonics does your country require? That sets the Q, unless you use other bandpass filters in later stages.

Answer (score 0):

Always start with design specs , not schematic. 
Define all impedances, Pin, Pout, IP3, and BW.

Parallel Q is Rp/X(f) while series Q is X(f)/Rs

Thus the Load is poorly matched to the parallel tank cct and needs rearrangement or a low Z buffer to drive series tank.

Class E alternates from open circuit to low RdsOn and thus yields low Q 1st stage with Rp=RdsOn/d for duty cycle , d

Also Coss affects Cp but only during transition across Vgs=Vth